# How to align a TextView according to its length

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

i have an interface with two ImageButtons and a TextView among them. The TextView contains a number and the two ImageButtons control that number, adding or removing 1.
The problem is when the number becomes two digits: the TextView width increase and one of two ImageButtons moves.

[image: One digit number]
[image: Two digit number]

As you can see when the number is one digit there isn't any type of problem, but when it becomes two digits the ImageButton moves from his place. I already tried with `android:layout_gravity` and with `android:gravity` but they doesn't function. There is a way to keep the TextView "centered" and make sure the ImageButton doesn't move?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foodName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="food_name"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foodQuantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#707070"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/removeFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove_black_40dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code and this is the layout of a RecyclerView member, because I created a personalized element.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `wrap_content` on your `foodQuantity` TextView, `addFood` is going to move to accommodate for the extra spacing required to add multiple digits. If you want to keep the position of the button fixed, and make sure the buttons don't move, then you are going to have to give your `TextView` a fixed width to accommodate for the maximum number of characters you can expect.

Comment: Okay, I understood. So I need to a set a fixed dimension for the textView in dp?

Comment: Yes. Instead of `wrap_content` give the `foodQuantity` a fixed width `60dp` or whatever width you feel works best for your design based on the maximum number of digits you will be supporting.

Comment: Ok, but will I have to adapt it for the different types of screen?

Comment: No. Your `foodName` TextView width will change its width according to device width, so no need to worry about different screen sizes in this case.

Comment: Okay, i put a size of 25 dp, it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `android:layout_weight` so you can define which element is filling the remaining space if necessary. So when setting the TextView a layout_weight of 1 and the ImageButtons a layout_weight of 0 you can afterwards set the `android:gravity` of the TextView that is defining the gravity inside of the TextView to `center` and it will always be centered.

**BUT**: you need to set the width of the `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` so it fills the parent. Without that the `LinearLayout` will never get some remaining space since it always shrinks to the size that all elements need together

Comment: Are you talking about the layout containing the ImageButtons and the textView?

Comment: So i tried what you suggest and if I set the linearLayout width to  `match_parent` it covers all the space.

Answer (score 0):

```java
...
...
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layout_count"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   or android:layout_width="match_parent
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_vertical">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_complete" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="1" />

      <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_complete" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_vertical">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_complete" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="1" />

      <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_complete" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand what is this.

Comment: If you try to use this code, you can understand. The code gives same as image you posted (left one). If you want, you can write 3 or 4 digits. Your images will not move.